# Changing ListView to GridView: java.lang.NullPointerException Error

Tags: android, json, android-listview, android-gridview, android-volley

I would like some help or suggestions regarding changing my `ListView` to a `GridView`. I am having problems adapting to it ever since I have rewritten some parts of my code in my `JeansActivity` so it can use a `GridView` but its showing me a `java.lang.NullPointerException` error:

```
04-12 19:28:36.194  21114-21114/com.dsgn.bbup E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.dsgn.bbup, PID: 21114
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dsgn.bbup/com.wlodsgn.bunbunup.JeansActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2202)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.dsgn.bbup.JeansActivity.onCreate(JeansActivity.java:90)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2252)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error might be shown under Line 90 which is `gridView.setAdapter(adapter)`

Here is the full code under the `OnCreate` method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_jeans);

        //Back button
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_main);
        actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        adapter = new GridAdapter(this, jeansGrid);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Cargando Productos...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));



        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest jeansReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener&lt;JSONArray&gt;() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i &lt; response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Jeans jeans = new Jeans();
                                jeans.setTitulo(obj.getString("titulo"));
                                jeans.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                jeans.setThumbnailUrl2(obj.getString("image2"));
                                jeans.setThumbnailUrl3(obj.getString("image3"));
                                jeans.setMarca(obj.getString("marca"));
                                jeans.setColor(obj.getString("color"));
                                jeans.setTipo(obj.getString("tipo"));
                                jeans.setRef(obj.getInt("ref"));

                                // adding jeans to jeans array
                                jeansGrid.add(jeans);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                hidePDialog();

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        /**AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(JeansReq);**/
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jeansReq);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView&lt;?&gt; parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String nombre = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.titulo))
                        .getText().toString();
                String brand = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.marca))
                        .getText().toString();
                String color = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.color))
                        .getText().toString();
                String tipo = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tipo))
                        .getText().toString();
                String ref = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ref))
                        .getText().toString();

                bitmap = ((Jeans) jeansGrid.get(position)).getThumbnailUrl();
                bitmap2 = ((Jeans) jeansGrid.get(position)).getThumbnailUrl2();
                bitmap3 = ((Jeans) jeansGrid.get(position)).getThumbnailUrl3();
                bitmapfull = ((Jeans) jeansGrid.get(position)).getThumbnailUrlFS();
                Intent intent = new Intent(JeansActivity.this, JeansDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(Titulo, nombre);
                intent.putExtra(Marca, brand);
                intent.putExtra(Colour, color);
                intent.putExtra(Tipo, tipo);
                intent.putExtra(Referencia, ref);
                intent.putExtra("image", bitmap);
                intent.putExtra("image2", bitmap2);
                intent.putExtra("image3", bitmap3);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

I have added a `GridAdapter` and the layouts for the GridView and its content `(activity_gridjeans.xml & grid_row.xml)`.

If need more info, let me know or you can check my project in [GitHub](https://github.com/wlopz/BBUp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/wlodsgn/bunbunup)[^]

Appreciate the help,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_jeans);
```

to

```
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_gridjeans);
```

This is your `activity_jeans.xml`. Look it has `ListView` not `GridView`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".VeroxActivity"
    android:background="#ff0a393d">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider2"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_row_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for viewing that small detail... Couldn't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 0):

Your layout `activity_jeans.xml` doesn't have a view with the name `gridView` thus

```
findViewById(R.id.gridView);
```

returns `null`.